# Correctly assign data to controls, SQL Server, VS2008

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

How may I correctly assign textboxes, dropdownlists & labels to appropriate fields, on successful retrieval of records via a SQL statement? I have 4 tables & therefore, the assigned data don't match the controls. (VS2008)

I have the following:

```
myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT pc.product_category_id, pc.product_category_name, pi.product_image_id, pi.product_image_filename, qr.qrcode_id, qr.qrcode_image_filename, p.product_author FROM Product AS p INNER JOIN ProductCategory AS pc ON p.product_category_id = pc.product_category_id INNER JOIN ProductImage AS pi ON p.product_image_id = pi.product_image_id INNER JOIN  QRCode AS qr ON p.qrcode_id = qr.qrcode_id WHERE p.product_id = '" & DropDownList2.Text & "'"

myCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@product_id", (DropDownList2.Text)))
myConn.Open()
'run the query and obtain a reader to get the results 
dtrReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

'check if there are results
If (dtrReader.Read()) Then
   'populate the values of the controls
   lblProductID2.Text = dtrReader(0)
   txtProductName2.Text = dtrReader(4)
   txtProductTitle2.Text = dtrReader(7)
   txtProductDescription2.Text = dtrReader(8)
   txtProductAuthor2.Text = dtrReader(12)
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks: I understand where you are coming from. Thank you, but with regards to the question, is there a simpler way out to match the fields?

Comment: What is incorrect / insufficient about your existing code?

Comment: @Dems: You see, when the retrieval is successful, for eg, lblProductID2.Text does not display its supposed value but the value taken from txtProductName2.Text. It has obviously got to do with the value within the parenthesis of dtrReader.

Comment: Would using `dataReader.GetOrdinal("myColumnName")` help to ensure that you're actually picking up the correct field numbers?

Comment: @Dems:yes, thank you. In a way, it lists out the supposed integers within the parenthesis, from there i can track & input the code provided as above. Worth the trouble to see things working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways to solve this:

1) Explicitly use the names of the columns when retrieving from datareader:

```
lblProductID2.Text = dtrReader("product_category_id")
' etc
```

2) Cycle through each of the fields in the reader and use a case statement to assign values

```
For nI As Integer = 0 To dtrReader.FieldCount - 1
   Select Case dtrReader.GetName(nI).ToLower()
      Case "product_category_id"
         If Not dtrReader.IsDBNull(nI) Then
             lblProductID2.Text = dtrReader.GetString(nI)
         Else
             lblProductID2.Text = String.Empty
         End If

      ' etc

   End Select
Next
```

Number 2 is probably slightly better because it makes it easier to test for DBNull values in the returned data:

Comment: Yes i believe that should do the job too. Much appreciated :)